# How to access websites inside iframe and search for things

Tags: php, jquery, iframe, jquery-plugins

hope that you're doing well, I'm trying to access Google.com and such as websites inside my iframe but it looks like it's blocked in my localhost, is there any way to do that? Maybe a jquery plugin that acts like a web browser? Here what I tried in my code in order to show Google.com in my website:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Test Page</title>
    <style type="text/css" href="style.css"></style>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/search?site=imghp&tbm=isch&q='searchstring'"></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="if1" width="100%" height="254" style="visibility:visible" src="http://www.google.com/custom?q=&btnG=Search"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: You cannot access the content of a cross-domain site through an iframe for security reasons. Imagine if this was possible, and then think how easy it would be to steal people's private information.

Comment: I can't disagree